# Unable to Debug/Install Watch App Extension

Tags: cocoapods, watchkit, watchos-2

I have been having this issue for quite some time and have been unable to fix this. About 90% of the time, my watch app fails to install on the device. The App will show installation to about 80% completion, then fail and quit, providing this error in the

**iPhone debug log console**

```
<Error>: 0x4029b000 __106-[ACXCompanionSyncConnectioninstallWatchAppWithBundleID:withProvisioningProfileInfo:completionWithError:]_block_invoke_3: Failed to install app com.mea.AppName.watchkitapp : Error Domain=ACXErrorDomain Code=17 "Got error 17 in install done from remote side (MI error ApplicationVerificationFailed ; Extended 0xe8008017 ; Desc Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.eC3skb/extracted/Payload/Watch.app/PlugIns/Watch Extension.appex : 0xe8008017 (A signed resource has been added, modified, or deleted.))" UserInfo={FunctionName=-[ACXServerInstallOperation receivedDictionaryOrData:], SourceFileLine=524, NSLocalizedDescription=Got error 17 in install done from remote side (MI error ApplicationVerificationFailed ; Extended 0xe8008017 ; Desc Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.eC3skb/extracted/Payload/Watch.app/PlugIns/Watch Extension.appex : 0xe8008017 (A signed resource has been added, modified, or deleted.))}
```

**Watch Debug Log Console**, these errors are thrown.

```
Verification stage failed
Jul 21 09:46:59 Andrews-AppleWatch appconduitd[104] <Error>: 0x1f084000 __MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices_block_invoke222: Returned error Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=13 "Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.eC3skb/extracted/Payload/Watch.app/PlugIns/Watch Extension.appex : 0xe8008017 (A signed resource has been added, modified, or deleted.)" UserInfo={LibMISErrorNumber=-402620393, LegacyErrorString=ApplicationVerificationFailed, FunctionName=+[MICodeSigningVerifier _validateSignatureAndCopyInfoForURL:withOptions:error:], NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.eC3skb/extracted/Payload/Watch.app/PlugIns/Watch Extension.appex : 0xe8008017 (A signed resource has been added, modified, or deleted.), SourceFileLine=142}
```

Because of these pod frameworks (which apparently have been modified) that I am using in my watch extension.

```
SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Jul 21 09:46:58 Andrews-AppleWatch installd[35] <Notice>: MIS: resource modified: /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.eC3skb/extracted/Payload/Watch.app/PlugIns/Watch Extension.appex/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
Jul 21 09:46:58 Andrews-AppleWatch installd[35] <Notice>: MIS: resource modified: /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.eC3skb/extracted/Payload/Watch.app/PlugIns/Watch Extension.appex/Frameworks/Realm.framework/Realm
Jul 21 09:46:58 Andrews-AppleWatch installd[35] <Notice>: MIS: resource modified: /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.eC3skb/extracted/Payload/Watch.app/PlugIns/Watch Extension.appex/Frameworks/RealmSwift.framework/RealmSwift
Jul 21 09:46:58 Andrews-AppleWatch installd[35] <Notice>: MIS: resource modified: /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.eC3skb/extracted/Payload/Watch.app/PlugIns/Watch Extension.appex/Frameworks/SwiftyJSON.framework/SwiftyJSON
```

Now, I understand that this has to do with code signing (right?), but how do I go about updating or verifying the correct code signature?

I see that other people have had a similar issue by having a non-alpha/non-numeric symbol in their Product Name, however, my Product name is AppNameWatch, and AppNameWatch Extension. Apple generates the Extension file with the space character in-between AppNameWatch and Extension, so I assume that that is fine and not the cause of the problem.

I have also tried cleaning/re-building/cleaning the build folder and deleting derived data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

**EDIT/UPDATE:**

Looks like this is an issue related to cocoapods. After moving all my frameworks to be managed by Carthage, the app is installing and running as it should with no errors related to modified resources.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem after I updated my project to use dynamic frameworks through `CocoaPods`. I had to go to the WatchKit Extension and change `Embedded Content Contains Swift Code` to `Yes`. Now the app builds and installs fine.